# bash while loop breaks after the first line

Tags: bash, while-loop

I have a simple script with while loop, but cannot understand, why it breaks after first line, from $vault_list variable:

```
#!/bin/bash

tech_login="$1"
vault_list=$(docker exec -i tmgnt_vault_1 vault list secret/${tech_login}-terminals | sed 1,2d)

while IFS= read -r terminal
do
    echo "line is $terminal"
    key_values=$(docker exec -i tmgnt_vault_1 vault read secret/${tech_login}-terminals/$terminal )


done <<< "$vault_list"
```

If I remove $key_values from while loop, it returns all values in echo "line is $terminal".
Can anyone point me, what is the problem with while loop? I assume, that this can be a problem with output, but not sure.

Comment: Does ```docker exec -i tmgnt_vault_1 vault read secret/${tech_login}-terminals/$terminal``` work if you run it separately?

Comment: yes, it returns values if I start it separately

Comment: Docker or the command you run inside it eats the rest of stdin, so there's nothing left to read in the next iteration.

Comment: Yes, that helps!

Comment: ugh :-P how do we stop it eating the rest of stdin ?

Comment: found it. for me ssh was eating stdin. direct ssh to take stdin from </dev/null solved it for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With hint from @choroba I found right syntax for $key_values:

```
key_values=$(docker exec -i tmgnt_vault_1 vault read secret/${tech_login}-terminals/$terminal <<<$terminal)
```

I was need to pass the $terminal variable explicitly to the docker command, which can be  done with a here-string,  "<<

Answer (score 4):

Hopefully this will help others.

ssh might be the command that is eating stdin.

It was for me.

e.g. ssh inside a while loop was causing the loop to exit after first iteration.

```
LIST="cid1 10.10.0.1 host1
cid2 10.10.0.2 host1
cid3 10.10.0.3 host2"

# this while loop exits after first iteration
# ssh has eaten rest of stdin
echo "$LIST" |while read -r cid cip chost; do
    echo $cid;
    PSINFO=$(ssh $chost docker exec -i $cid "ps -e -orss=,pid=,args=,cmd=" |grep java );
    echo PSINFO=$PSINFO; 
done;
```

SOLVED by directing ssh to take stdin from /dev/null using **</dev/null**:

```
# this while loop keeps on running
# ssh directed to take stdin from /dev/null
echo "$LIST" |while read -r cid cip chost; do
    echo $cid;
    PSINFO=$(ssh $chost docker exec -i $cid "ps -e -orss=,pid=,args=,cmd=" </dev/null |grep java );
    echo PSINFO=$PSINFO; 
done;
```

Comment: Yes. for sure, ssh consumes the stdin. You can use the -n flag to as in "ssh -n"  instead of < /dev/null. The code will look nicer and more readable. Check https://man.openbsd.org/ssh.1 and look for -n.

Comment: InteReStinG. Thank you. That looks like a proper solution rather than a hack redirecting /dev/null. Good to read up on ssh -n and -f flags.